# Excel file reopens with vertical bar symbol

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

When saving a file in Excel (tested as a CSV and Workbook), when reopening the file the commas have been converted into a vertical bar `|` (pipe symbol), and the columns have merged. What is causing this, and how can I prevent it?

[image: It looks like this]

Comment: How exactly you've saved the file?

Answer (score 1):

Open your Control Panel, then open Region. Within Region, click on the Additional Settings button.

In the List Separator field, change the Pipe to Comma. Click apply, ok, apply etc to save all your changes. The next time you save your CSV, you'll see commas rather than pipes and you won't have the merging issue, either.

[image]